# Stacking Washer and Dryer from different brands

Tags: dryer, washing-machine

I have a front loading washing machine and dryer from two different brands.
The washing machine is a [Samsung machine](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Samsung-High-Efficiency-Stackable-Front-Load-Washer-White-ENERGY-STAR/1002890950?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-vf-_-app-_-ggl-_-SS_APP_Appliances_VF-Samsung-_-1002890950-_-local-_-0-_-0&gclid=Cj0KCQjw3v6SBhCsARIsACyrRAkmJe0o7iE_Qo24LYmj_503upYLz4EZEAxqzVFDvIyfhoR3sIAFS-YaAs9rEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) and the dryer is a gas [Maytag](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Maytag-7-3-cu-ft-Reversible-Side-Swing-Door-Stackable-Gas-Dryer-White-ENERGY-STAR/5001115219). Can I stack them?

Comment: Sometimes getting the same brand makes things simpler or less expensive: adding in the time, hassle and cost of making a support solution often comes in more expensive & takes up more space etc

Comment: @SolarMike agreed :) There is a long background story here ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

People will often just build a shelf instead of buying machines that incorporate stacking systems.  You just need to be confident that you can build a shelf that will handle the weight.

You won't find something off the shelf for two different brands.

Answer (score 3):

Watch the electrical interconnections.   On some units, particularly those used in dense condo developments, they use "very special" units which have features that reduce the number of utilities that must be brought to the washer-dryer nook.

- Dryers that provide electrical to (and coordinate with) the washer:  eliminate sthe need for a 120/240V circuit
- Washers which heat the water: eliminates need for a hot water line
- Condensing OR heat pump dryers: eliminates need for exhaust vent

If you don't pay attention to those details, you can bring a new unit home and find nothing to hook it to.  Happens all the time.

Answer (score 1):

So long as they're the same size - width & depth, there shouldn't be any problem.  A lot of the stacking brackets/mounting rails for stacking units are universal anyway, if you want to go that route.  Something like this, from Amazon:

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/ANTOBLE-Laundry-Stacking-Replacements-Instructions/dp/B07MDF82WP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MDF82WP)

FWIW, my new dryers is just sitting on top of the washer with no brackets.

Comment: You just have it gravity stacked?  wow, I have a GE and an LG unit and the velocity and intensity of the washer spin cycle can walk the whole stacked unit.  I can't imagine having the dryer not attached.

Comment: I'm keeping a lose eye on it <wink>.  But after two or three weeks nothing has budged.  When I built the laundry room, I upped the size of the floor joists and put in additional blocking under where I knew the washer & dryer were going to go.  So there is little if any vibration in the floor.

Comment: That should be "close eye".